# Vue.js, VueX - cannot render data from API in a component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to make an API call to the server to fetch the data and then display them in a component. I have a `created()` method which dispatches an action to my store, which, in turn, commits the mutation to udpate my store with the data I got from the server. I also have `computed` method where I simply  call the getter which fetches the data from the store. The code looks like this:

## state

```
state: { 
    data: { 
        rides: [] 
    }
 }
```

## component.vue

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserRides');
}
computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
        'userRides'
    ]),
}
```

## store.js

//actions

```
fetchUserRides({ commit }) {
    axios.get('/api/stats/current_week')
        .then(response => {
            commit('fetchUserRides', response)
         })
        .catch(error => {
            commit('serverResponsError')
})
```

//mutations...

```
fetchUserRides(state, payload){
    let rides = payload.data
    rides.forEach((item) => {
        state.data.rides.push(item)
})
```

//getters

```
userRides: state => {
    let rides = state.data.rides
    rides.sort(( a, b) => {
        return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
    });
    return rides
}
```

I receive over 40 objects in the response, I did check it by `console.log(state.data.rides)` and they are there in 100%.

My problem is that when I log off and log back in again it throws an error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of null"`. But if I hit Refresh they appear fine. The login action redirects me to the page where I render this component. This looks like the computed property first tries to fetch data by the getter from the array before it is actually populated in the store. How can I make sure I get the array of objects in my component?

Comment: Your guess is correct. I would try to put some more console logs to get kinda feeling for what is going on and in which order. So you can debug indepth. You could try to wrap your component in a if statement like ```<template v-if="data.rides.count"> ... </template> ``` So your template or component will be rendered whenever you have an filled array of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set an empty array (`[]`) as an initial value to `state.data.rides` instead of `null`.

Another option will be to check that `rides` is truthy in your getters. 
Something like:

```
 if (rides) {
   rides.sort(( a, b) => {
     return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
   });
  }
  return []
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, rides is already initialized as an empty array in the store: `state: { data: { rides: [] } }`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my problem and it turns out I made a mistake. I completely forgot I set `state.data.rides = null` instead of an empty array `state.data.rides = null`, which would explain why the array was empty. It was a legacy code I had :)